# Can (R*,-) form a group?

Tags: group-theory

Can (R*,-) form a group? R*=R -{0}

I encountered this question somewhere, how can it form a group without identity element?

I had a question to show (R,+) and (R*,-) are not isomorphic!

Comment: Perhaps you meant $R^*$ under multiplication rather than subtraction.  Under multiplication, the identity element is $1$

Answer (score 4):

$$1\in\mathbb R^{*}$$ so if $\mathbb R^{*}=\mathbb R-\{0\}$ wants to be a group then we should have: $$1\color{red}{-}1\in\mathbb R^*$$

Answer (score 1):

$R^*$ is a group wrt the multiplication, but not wrt the addition.

They are not isomorphic e.g., because $(R,+)$ has a single root of the equation $x+x=0$, but $(R^*,\cdot)$ has two roots of the equation $x\cdot x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not associative: $(a - b) - c = a - (b + c)$, but that's not the same as $a - (b - c) = (a + c) - b$. So it's not a group at all.